# « Fixe » contre « fixé(e) »

Tags: usage

Souvent je me demande quand faut-il employer l'adjectif *fixe* et quand le participe passé *fixé(e)*. Par exemple, quelle est la différence entre :

> masse fixe et masse fixée

ainsi que

> volume fixe et volume fixé

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- « fixe » signifie une valeur constante, qui ne varie pas.
- « fixé(e) » signifie une valeur définie à l'avance.

Une valeur peut être à la fois « fixe » **et** « fixée ».